# Is it possible for an access database to become corrupted if it is only hit with select queries?

Tags: database, ms-access, corrupt-data

Is it possible for an access database to become corrupted if it is only hit with select queries?  One of our databases got corrupted seemingly out of the blue.  Is this possible?

Comment: You may wish to read http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/corruptmdbs.htm

Answer (score 2):

I would have to say "no", because technically "corrupted" means "the data is inconsistent", which can only happen if it has changed (due to update).

However, you can get earlier disk failure due to excessive reading of the data from disk, so your database get still "die" due to that.